# How to make media queries work exclusively (if elseif else)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

The common way to make different styles for different widths is by making multiple @media queries, for example:

```
@media(min-width:1200px){ ... }

@media(min-width:768px){ ... }

@media(min-width:576px){ ... }

@media(min-width:320px){ ... }
```

but using this method the rules are not exclusive, for example the rules in (min-width:768px) are applied for >1200px

I want to make them work exclusively, Any Ideas?

## What I tried

### max-width and min-width

```
@media(min-width:1200px){ ... }

@media(max-width:1199px) and (min-width:768px){ ... }

...
```

the problem with this method that you have the interval between 1199 and 1200px that is neglected

### not all and min-width

```
@media(min-width:1200px){ ... }

@media not all and (min-width:1200px){ ... }

...
```

the problem with this method that it can be used only if you have two intervals like >=1200px and <1200px, but in my case I have many intervals

### @when

```
@when media(min-width:1200px){ ... }

@else{ ... }

...
```

I found this method in some blogs but when I searched for what browsers accept it I couldn't find, it seems that it's a new query that may not be accepted by many browsers

## My example

```css
.row{
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.cell{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.img{
  position: relative;
  background-color: navy;
  height: 100%;
}

.img:hover{
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 3;
  transition: background-color .3s;
}

/* Only width>768px: */

.cell:nth-child(4n+1) .img, .cell:nth-child(4n+2) .img{
  width: 100%;
}
.cell:nth-child(4n+1) .img:hover, .cell:nth-child(4n+2) .img:hover{
  width: 200%;
  transition: width .5s;
}

.cell:nth-child(4n) .img:hover, .cell:nth-child(4n-1) .img:hover{
  margin-left: -100%;
  transition: margin-left .5s;
}

/*
Only when there are three cells in the line, ie. width>=576px and <768

.cell:nth-child(3n+1) .img, .cell:nth-child(3n+2) .img{
  width: 100%;
}
.cell:nth-child(3n+1) .img:hover, .cell:nth-child(3n+2) .img:hover{
  width: 200%;
  transition: width .5s;
}

.cell:nth-child(3n) .img:hover{
  margin-left: -100%;
  transition: margin-left .5s;
}

*/


/*
Only when there are two cells in the line, ie. width<576px

.cell:nth-child(2n+1) .img{
  width: 100%;
}
.cell:nth-child(2n+1) .img:hover{
  width: 200%;
  transition: width .5s;
}

.cell:nth-child(2n) .img:hover{
  margin-left: -100%;
  transition: margin-left .5s;
}

*/
```

```html
<head><link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous"></head>
<body>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="cell col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <div class="img"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <div class="img"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <div class="img"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <div class="img"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <div class="img"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <div class="img"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <div class="img"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <div class="img"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <div class="img"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You tagged this `responsive-design` but this would not really responsive design. This would be targeting specific screen sizes exclusively, so the opposite. Why would you even like to set up something like this?

Comment: the problem is that i am targeting different attributes in these queries so if they're not exclusive they won't override each other, for example in some intervals i am using the width attribute but in others i want to use margin-left without initializing the width.

Comment: This does not sound like a thought out approach for setting up your CSS (or like a not friendly design /layout) ... Can you share some designs on why you need that many differences?

Comment: https://codepen.io/mhtixcnu-the-typescripter/pen/yLpNJyz
Like this example i want to make first two cells enlarge to the right, and the second two cells to enlarge to the left. But that's when there are 4 cells in each line if there are two i need it to be only the first cell enlarge to the right the second to left (the code commented)